# Proving that $f'(z)\neq0$ when $|z|=1$ for a continuous, analytic $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f(z)$ is analytic when $|z|<1$, and it's continuous when $|z|\leq 1$.
> Prove that $f'(z)$ can't be $0$ when $|z|=1$. f(z) is not a constant, and |f(z0)|=max(|z|≤1)|f(z)|,for all |z0|=1

Need some help here.I had considered about the maxium modulus principle, but I didn't get a result

Comment: you need some extra conditions here as $z^2-2z$ is definitely analytic in the full plane and has a critcial point at $1$

Comment: Also any constant function would contradict this. Even with the specification by peter above this comment.

Comment: sorry bros, I missed some conditions here: f(z) is not a constant, and |f(z0)|=max(|z|≤1)|f(z)|,for all |z0|=1

Comment: You should repair the question! Note the "Edit" link...

Comment: @NimaMiao May I gently suggest that you not address people as 'bros'... After all, there are women on the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic on $|z|<1$ and continuous on $|z|\le 1$ then for $|z|<1$, $2i\pi f(z)=\int_{|s|=1} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$. If $g(t)=f(e^{it})$ is differentiable with $g'(t)=0$ then $f(e^{it}) =f(1)$ so $f$ is constant.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f'(z) = 0$ for *all* $z$ with $|z|=1$? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't assume that $f$ is complex differentiable on the boundary. I think it *might* be what the OP was given, if it isn't then it isn't a big deal

Comment: Thanks bro, I think you just got what am I trying to ask。